# How to Load Kendo Grid in Window and useHidden Fields for Parameter Values

Tags: .net-core, kendo-grid

I have an index.cshtml that loads a grid of Agencies.
Clicking a custom button in the grid opens a window and loads a BillingRates grid in a partial view for the selected agency.
I read two parameters from the Agencies grid and want to use them for the datasource parameters of the BillingRates grid.

What is the best way to do that?
I have two hidden fields on the index.cshtml that store the two parameters I read from the Agencies grid.  A javascript alert tells me the values are correct, but the hidden fields come up "undefined" though they are there and their values get posted -- I changed the fields to textboxes instead of hidden to prove this.

Here's my code:
hidden fields on index.cshtml (showing text here for testing)

```
<input type="text" value="" name="pidForBillingRates" />
<input type="text" value="" name="aidForBillingRates" />
```

custom button click event:

```
function ShowManageBillingRatesWindow_Click(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
var pid = dataItem.Provider;
var aid = dataItem.AgencyId;
$("#pidForBillingRates").val(pid);
$("#aidForBillingRates").val(aid);
alert("pidForBillingRates = " + $("#pidForBillingRates"));
alert("pidForBillingRates.val() = " +     
$("#pidForBillingRates").attr('value'));
alert("aidForBillingRates.val() = " +
$("#aidForBillingRates").attr('value'));
alert("pid = " + pid + " and aid = " + aid);

$('#manageBillingRatesWindow').load('@Url.Action("AgencyBillingRateView",    
"AgencyBillingRate")' + "?providerId=" + pid + "&agencyId=" + aid);
var window = $("#manageBillingRatesWindow").data("kendoWindow");
window.center().open();
}
```

The first alert:

```
alert("pidForBillingRates = " + $("#pidForBillingRates"));
```

comes back with: 
    {object object} 
so I know it finds the textbox.

The second alert:

```
alert("pidForBillingRates.val() = " +     
$("#pidForBillingRates").attr('value'));
```

comes back "Cannot read value of undefined."

The third alert:

```
alert("aidForBillingRates.val() = " +
$("#aidForBillingRates").attr('value'));
```

comes back "Cannot read value of undefined."

The fourth alert"

```
alert("pid = " + pid + " and aid = " + aid);
```

comes back with the correct values for pid and aid.

I tried putting the hidden fields (textbox fields for testing) on the index.cshtml, and then on the BillingRates partial view but still get the same undefined messages.

So the grid does not load any data because it's not retrieving the two necessary parameters in the filter it uses.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You have to used val() function to get value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that "it finds the textbox" `pidForBillingRates`. The hash sign tells jQuery to search for an element with the id "pidForBillingRates". What you want is to search for an element with an attribute `name` and the attribute value "pidForBillingRates". So `$("input[name='pidForBillingRates']")` should give you the correct element.

See https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for all supported selectors in jQuery.

Comment: Thank you Carsten Franke; The ShowManageBillingRatesWindow_Click function still gives an undefined for those two text fields, however by using your suggestion, it does work in the filter for the datasource of the grid.

`function billingRatesFilter(e) {
        pid = $("input[name='pidForBillingRates']");
        aid = $("input[name='aidForBillingRates']");
        alert("billingRatesFilter aidForBillingRates = " + aid.val());
        return { providerId: pid.val(), agencyId: aid.val() };
   etc.
I think it doesn't work in the click event because of the page refresh. Not sure. Thanks!

Comment: Please, update your question with your current code. It is much easier to understand where your problem occurs.